# Facebook actions like spotify?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to understand actions and objects on facebook and im completely blown away by how spotify publishes actions with that format. How the heck do you customize the layout of a user's action like that?

As far as im concern, with facebook's lovely documentation, all you can do is  publish actions on a single line : (user A) -- (action) -- on -- (object) followed by a title and description.

How do you design html/css layout of a user's actions? Link? Attachment? I'm guessing you have to do some sort of "magic" on the description? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's open Graph Tutorial does a decent job of explaining this but with the various options you have to scroll for a while to make it to the grouping part. In short, the individual actions you're familiar with combine together via "aggregations" which can be set to show a number of formats from lists to grids.

To set one of these up you must configure your Actions and Objects via the open graph settings first and then manually create an aggregation and a few defaults to fill in for preview purposes.

This will show up when a user authenticates your app for open graph and becomes customized to them as they start actually using said actions.

Now as for the play button option, that's something I assume is unique to their integration.

Documents at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/